# Text field isn't showing on iPad simulator (on iPhone yes)

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ipad, uitextfield

I'm making app for iPhone and iPad. I have table view with only one row and in this row I have UITextField. On iPhone simulator (also on physical device) I have no problem. But when I try to run the app on iPad simulator (2, Retina or Air, doesn't matter) it just show empty row. This is big issue because this app has to be primary for iPad. Does anybody know where is problem? Thank you very much

I made simple project only with table view and textfield (TableViewController):

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // OUTLETS:

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!


    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Check in the  Attributes Inspector, that the textfield is installed in iPad or not, for the corresponding size class,(there is a check box at the last of the Attributes Inspector).

Comment: Welcome.. :-) #Lachtan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rajram answered my question but because comment can't be accepted so there's just copy of his answer.

> Check in the Attributes Inspector, that the textfield is installed in
>   iPad or not, for the corresponding size class,(there is a check box at
>   the last of the Attributes Inspector)